# PHP Puzzle: Unique Styles with PHP loop

Tags: php, custom-field, metabox, css

**The Puzzle:**
I am currently working on a music blog that has various venues and numerous locations that are laid out at the top of each post as follows:

**USA.California.Los Angeles.** Hollywood Bowl

*Note: Everything except the venue name (Hollywood Bowl) is bold.*

In order to limit the number of calls to the server I have clumped all the title information into a single array (as seen below).
[image]
[image]

As of now I am simply calling everything in the array consecutively:

```
<?php $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID); 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)  {
        if(isset($custom_fields["rw_location_$i"])){ ?>
            <h1><?php echo get_post_meta ($post->ID,"rw_location_$i", true ); ?></h1>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
```

**The Question:**
How do I still make a "single call" but create a unique class (h1,h2,h3) for different `$i`? For example have the `$i = 1` be a `<h1></h1>` tag and `$i = 2,3,4` be `<h2></h2>` tags.

I hope my question is clear enough, if not I'd be happy to elaborate further.

(P.S. I know the numbering is off, but I'm sure we can all overlook that)

Comment: The quick fix.. `<h<?php echo $i; ?>><?php echo get_post_meta ($post->ID,"rw_location_$i", true ); ?></h<?php echo $i; ?>>` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To are still call database inside the by `get_post_meta()` where you already have the values in `$custom_fields` variable. Try something like this:

```
 <?php

    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID); 
      for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)  {
       if(isset($custom_fields["rw_location_$i"][0])){ 
        if($i==1){ echo '<h1>';} else {echo '<h2>';}
        echo $custom_fields["rw_location_$i"][0] 
        if($i==1) {echo '</h1>'; }else {echo '</h2>'};
       }
    } 
  ?>
```

If I get your question right. Are you looking to echo `<h1>` for the first iteration and `<h2>` for all other iteration?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Just one minor related question. Is it proper to echo so many times? I mean I see no reason why not but wanted to double check if this was the only **practical** method for fulfilling my needs. I don't know why but I always get the feeling adding too many echoes it's like adding too many unnecessary div's to a html doc.

Comment: I see no problem with that. I don't know if its affect the performance or not. You can do concatenation http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php to save the html in a variable and echo outside of the loop if you want. Thanks! :)